# Can I change the format of a flat file connection without losing all my columns?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is there are any way to change a fixed-width flat file connection manager to delimited format without losing all the column definitions?  I'm using SSIS 2005, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Barry: Not sure I understand your question.  My problem is that when I change the format all my column definitions disappear, or "reset to their defaults" in Microsoftese.

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your question.  I thought you were asking what will happen.

Comment: Good question. I have suffered with that as well :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, which is unfortunate.